# Apache Beam Windowing on a signals phase

Tags: apache-beam

**Updated**: Is it possible to window a data stream on a [signals phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves)).

For example, there is a stream of timestamp, key, value:

`[<t0, k1, 0>, <t1, k1, 98>, <t2, k1, 145>, <t4, k1, 0>, <t3, k1, 350>, <t5, k1, 40>, <t6, k1, 65>, <t7, k1, 120>, <t8, k1, 240>, <t9, k1, 352>]`.

The output would be two windows for key k1:

- t0 - t3: `[0, 98, 145, 350]`
- t4 - t9: `[0, 40, 65, 120, 240, 352]`

E.g. every time the value hits 0, start a new window for the group.

Answer (score 1):

After your question edit and use case clarification I would recommend to look into custom windowing to extend the standard [sessions](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Sessions.java). As a starting point I built the following example (it can be improved upon).

Through `WindowFn.AssignContext` we can access the [`element()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.AssignContext.html#element--) that it's being windowed into a proto-session. If it's equal to a given `stopValue` the window length will be confined to the minimum instead of using `gapDuration` for that purpose:

```java
@Override
public Collection<IntervalWindow> assignWindows(AssignContext c) {
  Duration newGap = c.element().getValue().equals(this.stopValue) ? new Duration(1) : gapDuration;
  return Arrays.asList(new IntervalWindow(c.timestamp(), newGap));
}
```

Then, when merging the sorted windows we'll check if they do overlap but also that the window duration is not equal to 1 ms.

```java
Collections.sort(sortedWindows);
List<MergeCandidate> merges = new ArrayList<>();
MergeCandidate current = new MergeCandidate();
for (IntervalWindow window : sortedWindows) {
  // get window duration and check if it's a stop session request
  Long windowDuration = new Duration(window.start(), window.end()).getMillis();

  if (current.intersects(window) && !windowDuration.equals(1L)) {
    current.add(window);
  } else {
    merges.add(current);
    current = new MergeCandidate(window);
  }
}
merges.add(current);
for (MergeCandidate merge : merges) {
  merge.apply(c);
}
```

Of course, we also can add some code so that we can provide different stopping values: a `stopValue` field, a `withStopValue` method, constructors, display data if using the Dataflow Runner, etc.

```java
/** Value that closes the session. */
private final Integer stopValue;

/** Creates a {@code StopSessions} {@link WindowFn} with the specified gap duration. */
public static StopSessions withGapDuration(Duration gapDuration) {
  return new StopSessions(gapDuration, 0);
}

/** Creates a {@code StopSessions} {@link WindowFn} with the specified stop value. */
public StopSessions withStopValue(Integer stopValue) {
  return new StopSessions(gapDuration, stopValue);
}

/** Creates a {@code StopSessions} {@link WindowFn} with the specified gap duration and stop value. */
private StopSessions(Duration gapDuration, Integer stopValue) {
  this.gapDuration = gapDuration;
  this.stopValue = stopValue;
```

Now in our pipeline we can import and use the new `StopSessions` class with:

```java
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.StopSessions; // custom one
...

.apply("Window into StopSessions", Window.<KV<String, Integer>>into(StopSessions
  .withGapDuration(Duration.standardSeconds(10))
  .withStopValue(0)))
```

To mimic your example we create some data with:

```java
.apply("Create data", Create.timestamped(
    TimestampedValue.of(KV.of("k1", 0), new Instant()), // <t0, k1, 0>
    TimestampedValue.of(KV.of("k1",98), new Instant().plus(1000)), // <t1, k1, 98>
    TimestampedValue.of(KV.of("k1",145), new Instant().plus(2000)), // <t2, k1, 145>
    TimestampedValue.of(KV.of("k1",0), new Instant().plus(4000)), // <t4, k1, 0>
    ...
```

With standard sessions the output would be:

```java
user=k1, scores=[0,145,350,120,0,40,65,98,240,352], window=[2019-06-08T19:13:46.785Z..2019-06-08T19:14:05.797Z)
```

And with the custom one I get the following:

```java
user=k1, scores=[350,145,98], window=[2019-06-08T21:18:51.395Z..2019-06-08T21:19:03.407Z)
user=k1, scores=[0], window=[2019-06-08T21:18:54.407Z..2019-06-08T21:18:54.408Z)
user=k1, scores=[65,240,352,120,40], window=[2019-06-08T21:18:55.407Z..2019-06-08T21:19:09.407Z)
user=k1, scores=[0], window=[2019-06-08T21:18:50.395Z..2019-06-08T21:18:50.396Z)
```

Changing the `stopValue` with `.withStopValue(<int>)` works as expected. The `98, 145 and 350` events are in a different session than the rest. Please note that this is not exactly like in the description as the `stopValue` gets assigned to a separate window instead of the new one but it can be filtered downstream and it gives you an idea on how to proceed. I would like to revisit this and also look for a Python implementation, too.

All files [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/46e938a358db3826be3d0bf53dc8726c).

Answer (score 0):

Likely not, from your description. There are at least two problems:

- `PCollections` in Beam are unordered and distributed:

  - there are no guarantees in the model that events from one group will arrive in that order;
- data-driven triggers are not supported (probably for similar reasons):

  - https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#data-driven-triggers

However you can look into stateful processing and see if you can handle this manually. E.g. you accumulate all the incoming events in the state and then from time to time analyze the accumulated events and emit the results.

Or if you can extract/assign a common key in your business logic, then you might want to check if `GroupByKey+ParDo` or `Combine` would be helpful.

See:

- https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zf9TxIOsZf_fz86TGaiAQqdNI5OO7Sc6qFsxZlBAMiA/edit
- https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine
- https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey

Comment: I updated the question to incorporate a common key and unordered events. Data-drive triggers would be required if a phase condition is never hit, the window still needs to fire at some point. Could it be possible to use some sort stateful processing in combination with a custom windowFn? This would create a data-driven window where the start & end time are not fixed or sliding, but data driven. Somewhat like a Session Window except instead of the condition being the absence of data for a period of time, it is when a particular condition is hit.